# Is there any way to fix APP not installed?

Tags: java, android

When I build signed APK it's installing without any problem, but when I uninstall it and trying to install it again it's says `App not installed`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissioenter image description herens" />
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[1]:

Comment: Are you facing this problem for a particular device? or for all the devices?

Comment: I have 4 phones same error, some times i can install it but if I uninstall it and reinstalling it it's says app not installed.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I am not an android expert, but my gut feeling is that you the information in your question is insufficient to help you.

Comment: Hi @jowan did you find any solution to this problem. I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: @beginner Hi, you should write you informations correctly.

Comment: @jowan Hi, my question is exactly as same as yours, thats why i directly asked whether you found solution to that problem. So, did you found any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install a copy of your app in your device via Android Studio (via Run) before?

If Yes, then you must've also uinstalled it before pushing the signed version but apps installed via ADB (A.S) aren't uinstalled completely...

Go to Settings > Apps & Notifications > Find your App > Click on the 3 dots on Toolbar > Uninstall for All Users...

Now try installing your App

Comment: I uninstall it and deleted cash files as well, I face same issue for phones i never installed it on.

Comment: Have you signed it with V2 Full Apk Signature? If yes, try signing without it

Comment: same problem, first time has installed normally, after i uninstalled it and tried to installing it again it's says App not installed.