# Android app fails to install from transfer to new device after Android Studio update

Tags: android, installation, transfer

I created an app on Android Studios using my Samsung S4 mini and then transferred the app onto my much newer Samsung A7, which worked fine.

However, I decided to update Android Studios and since then, while it still works fine installed directly from Android Studios, after I transfer the app to my A7, it won't install- it seems to mostly install and then stops at the end with a 'did not install' message.

Thinking it was a problem with my project, I created a new project and tried the same thing with it as is, but with the same result. 
I checked my permissions and the transfer app I'm using has permission to install apps. 
I tried using a different transfer app, but still the same.
I even uninstalled the app on the Samsung S4 (where it was working because I directly installed it from Android Studio) and then transferred the file from my A7 to my S4 and it wouldn't install on the S4 either.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: which Android Studio version you are using right now? 3.2.1?

Comment: Maybe it's not your case, but before installing the application, check that it's not installed in the device already.

Comment: maybe try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314056/6819340

Comment: @VirajPatel Yes, 3.2.1

Comment: I don't think previous installations are the problem because the same thing happened when I created a new project and tried to install it for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not distribute APKs which are installed directly from Android Studio 3.2 and greater version.

If you wish to share APK file then follow below steps:

Goto **Build menu -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)**

[image: Build APK(s)]

**Once APK is created it will display popup like below in bottom right corner:**

[image: Build APK Location]

On Click of **locate** it will take you to your APK's folder.

You will find **app-debug.apk** in the folder which you can share and install in the devices.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Thanks for accepting my answer. You can upvote my answer as well.